# Android phone has SMS messages not sorted chronologically by date

Tags: sms, date-and-time

I have an old phone Huawei Y635 with Android 4.4.4 KitKat. The problem is that all SMS messages are messed up not following chronologically by date.

I tried everything I read on the internet but had no success (setting time by the carrier, time zone by the carrier, restart the phone, power off then power on, etc.). I also installed "SMS Time Fix" from Google Play Store but no success.

One thing I haven't tried was a factory reset, I would like not to do it.

I appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, after long research, I found a solution for my issue: I haven't paid attention to one detail of the messages that were out of order. All these messages have a blue mark at the top right corner in the shape of a blue triangle. This means that the messages were PINNED to the top list of SMS messages.

The solution is to select these messages then select the option to UNPIN them. Now everything is in order, no need to download any (spyware) app in the Play Store.